# Linux shell script livecopy of current line

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, user-input

I need a way to use the current line which the users typed into as variable for a shell function.

my current code, which can be called by ctrl+r

```
zle -N search

bindkey "^R" search

search () {
read str;
fc -ln -30 | grep $str;
}
```

or simply, to call it as a function

```
search () {
fc -ln -30 | grep $1;
}
```

target pseudo code, to call as a function called by ctrl+r that needs no further input prompt

```
zle -N search

bindkey "^R" search

search () 
fc -ln -30 | grep -->vodoo-function-that-returns-current-line<--;
}
```

Comment: for people who found this and are searching for a solution http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152263/how-can-you-get-the-current-terminal-line-the-one-that-is-still-editable-by-the

Answer (score 0):

for people who found this and are searching for a solution [How can you get the current terminal line (the one that is still editable by the user)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152263/how-can-you-get-the-current-terminal-line-the-one-that-is-still-editable-by-the) –  user3979266